# Q: How ListNode storing sum works in LinkedList Add Two Numbers: LeetCode (JS)

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I've been trying to understand the solution for problem "2. Add Two Numbers" with reversed linked lists in LeetCode using JS.

I don't understand the behavior of dummyHead variable after reassigning current to current.next. Now when I add next value via current.next = new ListNode(x), I would expect that this new value x wouldn't be added to dummyHead as I've previously reassigned the current to current.next, but it doesn't behave that way. This new value is also added to dummyHead. Can someone explain to me why is that?

Code:

```
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
    let dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
    let p1 = l1;
    let p2 = l2;
    let current = dummyHead;
    let carry = 0;
    
    while(p1 !== null || p2 !== null){
        console.log("Head, current before:", dummyHead, current)
        x = p1 !== null ? p1.val : 0;
        y = p2 !== null ? p2.val : 0;
        let sum = x + y + carry;
        
        carry = Math.floor(sum/10);
        current.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        console.log("head, current middle:", dummyHead, current);
        current = current.next;
        console.log("head, current after:", dummyHead, current);
        
        if(p1 !== null){
            p1 = p1.next;
        }
        if(p2 !== null){
            p2 = p2.next;
        }
    }
    
    if (carry > 0) {
        current.next = new ListNode(carry);
    }
    
    console.log("HEAD", dummyHead);
    return dummyHead.next;
     
};
```

Example:
Input:

```
[2,4,3]
[5,6,4]
```

stdout:

```
Head, current before: [0] [0]
head, current middle: [0,7] [0,7]
head, current after: [0,7] [7]
Head, current before: [0,7] [7]
head, current middle: [0,7,0] [7,0]
head, current after: [0,7,0] [0]
Head, current before: [0,7,0] [0]
head, current middle: [0,7,0,8] [0,8]
head, current after: [0,7,0,8] [8]
HEAD [0,7,0,8]
```

Comment: "*I would expect that this new value x wouldn't be added to dummyHead as I've previously reassigned the current to current.next*" the code is *first* adding to `dummyHead` here `current.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);` (because `current = dummyHead` at the start) and *then* reassigning `current = current.next;`. So, the list is `dummyHead -> sum % 10` at this point.

Comment: But what happens if we are in the second iteration and we've already reassigned the current to current.next in first iteration? I would say that in the second iteration it shouldn't add to dummyHead anymore as we've reassigned current to current.next before.

Comment: On the second iteration you're adding onto the *second* element. So you get a list of `dummyHead -> sum % 10 -> sum % 10`

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now, many thanks.